# In a MAAS/juju setup, is it possible to deploy multiple charms (eg. mysql and wordpress) on one single MAAS node?

Tags: juju, maas

Well the headline basically says it all.

I have a small testing environment running, and this question pops up. Not all charms need a whole node for them selves. Is it possible for me to deploy both mysql and wordpress charm on one machine?

If yes, how do i do that. And yes, i have been looking around and also found something called subordinate services which could look like a solution to that, but i am not sure and defiantly not sure how to set that up..

Anyone who can help me here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--to` is what you looking for:

```
juju deploy wordpress --to 0
juju deploy mysql --to 0
```

Will deploy to the same `0` node.

#### References and examples:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying#deploying-to-specific-machines-and-containers

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can also use linux containers on the same machine or even your local machine. With linux containers you'll have some form of isolation between processes and each charm will get its own IP address from the DHCP server on your dedicated subnet (if you have a DHCP server installed).

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/config-local

This is working for local openstack test environments, but its not working for all charms. In particular it has problems with deploying wordpress.

[Wordpress deployed with LXC fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648896/wordpress-deployed-with-juju-using-lxc-fail)

If you have a physical machine at you disposal you can try this:

```
juju deploy --to lxc:0 mysql
juju deploy --to lxc:0 wordpress
juju add-relation mysql:db wordpress:db
juju expose wordpress
```

This will deploy mysql and wordpress on machine0 (your first juju machine) and both in isolated linux containers.

You can find some great articles about LXC in the following series:

[Your first Ubuntu Container](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/20/lxc-1-0-your-first-ubuntu-container/)

In general it is adviced not to deploy charms without any form of isolation (aka without LXC/LXD/KVM) on the same machine. But in this case, I believe, you are stuck with doing just that.